# Is it correct to say that the two electrons in an orbital spin in opposite directions?

Tags: electrons

Are the electrons actually spinning at all?
If no, what does the spin really mean?
If yes, do they have to spin in opposite directions? Are these directions clockwise and anticlockwise?

Answer (score 2):

Electrons don't literally spin about some axis, like miniature spinning tops. Electrons do have a quantum property, an *intrinsic angular momentum*, which we refer to as *spin*.

An electron has a spin quantum number usually denoted as $m_s$ which can only take on two values: $m_s= \pm \frac{1}{2}$, sometimes referred to as as 'up' or 'down'.

Two electrons in the same orbital, share values of the three other quantum numbers $n$, $l$ and $m_l$ and the [Pauli Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_exclusion_principle) then dictates that they must have different values for $m_s$, i.e. one must have the value $+\frac{1}{2}$ and the other $-\frac{1}{2}$, or vice versa. In that sense, two electrons sharing an orbital will always have different spin 'directions' even though there is no Classical spinning.

Comment: I think, OP is thinking the electron as a particle. And so he wrote `Are the electrons actually spinning at all?` BTW, it would be better if you just at least mention _spin-orbital_ & also _asymetrisation_ of the wavefunction; otherwise it was a nice explanation:)

Comment: If the electrons aren't literally spinning, what do you exactly mean by different spin 'directions'? I was just reading the fourth chapter Clayden & Warren where it says: 'Well, electrons have the property of spin, and the two electrons allowed in each orbital have to spin in opposite directions.' Similarly, Solomons & Fryhle write: 'An electron spins about its own axis.' Then there's Morrison & Boyd: 'This electron spins and thus generates a magnetic moment.' I can't believe all these books are lying  to me! Whom should I trust?!

Comment: @shawn: In the modern interpretation of QM we don't even consider electrons as particles, rather as *excitations of the quantum field*. The books you quote aren't *lying*, they're just a bit behind the times! ;-)